# Please help me get emacsclient working

Tags: emacsclient

- OS X 10.11
- Emacs 24.5: `/Applications/Emacs.app`
- emacsclient: `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient`
- `(server-start)` in my `.emacs` file
- `% emacsclient some-file`

Result is:

> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient:
>   can't find socket; have you started the server? To start the server in
>   Emacs, type "M-x server-start".
>
> /Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin-x86_64-10_9/emacsclient: No
>   socket or alternate editor.  Please use:
>
> --socket-name   --server-file      (or environment variable
>   EMACS_SERVER_FILE)    --alternate-editor (or environment variable
>   ALTERNATE_EDITOR)

I have also tried this running Emacs and emacsclient as installed with MacPorts with the same result.

This is been happening for many years. I can't even remember the last time I was able to use emacsclient. I have searched extensively for information about this, but all I can find is information I already know as a sophisticated Emacs user of many decades.

I am not looking to run Emacs as a daemon.

Suggestions?

Comment: You want an emacs server to run, but not as a daemon? Isn't this the whole point of an emacs server?

Comment: Not at all. All documentation says you can run it either way and which way you do it is a matter of preference. As an experiment I guess I should try it as a daemon, but it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Try running `M-x server-force-delete`.  If the server is really running, you should see a message like `Connection file "/tmp/emacs101/server" deleted"`.  If you don't see a message like that, you may not have a running server after all.

Answer (score 1):

`emacsclient` with no option contacts a running Emacs. You need to either start Emacs with your session (presumably as a daemon) or instruct emacsclient to start Emacs if there isn't one already.

To instruct emacsclient to start Emacs if it isn't already running, run either

```
emacsclient --alternate-editor=''
```

or

```
emacsclient -a ''
```

(You can put this in a shell alias or in a wrapper script.)

Comment: I neglected to say in my OP that Emacs.app is running, but I did say that `(server-start) is in my `.emacs` file. So indeed, I want `emacsclient` to contacts my running Emacs.app.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I was running emacsclient from /usr/bin/emacsclient, now I use this:

```
export EDITOR='/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/emacsclient --no-wait --alternate-editor=/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs'
alias e=$EDITOR
```